# Style list header for numeric column

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, list

I am using the following css to style the headers of a list:

```
.ms-vh, .ms-vh2-nofilter, .ms-vh2-nograd, .ms-vh2, .ms-vb{
      text-align:left;
      color:red;
  }
```

This seems to work for every column except for columns with 'number' as data type. How to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to include at least `.ms-vh2 a` in addition to what you have. Based on my tests the column using the type of `Number` uses this class.

[image]

Update: To apply the `text-align:left` styling, the `.ms-vh2 .ms-numHeader` class should be included.

Comment: Thanks. The color changes, but the text-align is unchanged. It is important that all column header text is aligned left.

Comment: @CitizenDB for me using `text-align:left !Important` did the trick. EDIT: or not - also include the class `.ms-vh2 .ms-numHeader`!

Comment: Thanks! ms-numHeader did the trick. Please update your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @CitizenDB: updated.

Comment: for other fields types you can use this css code in the header of SharePoint list :   .ms-vh-div {
    text-align:left
}